# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2 to Person (VB.Net)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know there are other threads on SO concerning this error, and know what the error means.  However, I cannot figure where the fix code in my own case.

I need to return an `IEnumerable(Of Person)` from an API.  Previously I used a `For Each` loop, but was investigating using (much) less code to achieve the same result.  I'm not sure if I've shortcutted too far here (perhaps hoping for a one-line nirvana...)

```
Public Function [Get]() As IEnumerable(Of Person)
    Using dt As DataTable = LoadDataTable()
        Return New List(Of Person)() From {
            From dr In dt.Rows Select New Person() With {
                .FirstName = dr.Item("FirstName").ToString(),
                .Surname = dr.Item("Surname").ToString()
            }
        }
    End Using
End Function
```

The error is:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Object, MyApp.Models.Person]'
>   to type 'MyApp.Models.Person'

I guessed at placing the `.ToList()` extension method in different places, but can't get it right.  Can anyone advise if this is all possible in a single operation, or if I have no choice to but declare a `New List` variable?

Comment: What happens if, instead of returning `New List ... From`, you instead put parens around your `From ... Select` and do `ToList` on that?  Alternatively, what happens if, instead of using `From` on the new list, you instead use your `From ... Select` as the argument to the ctor?  It looks to me like VB is expecting one or more Person objects in the braces after the list `From`, and instead is getting an enumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put what @Craig said into an answer, `From` expects a comma separated list of whatever type you're using(in this case `Person`), not another collection.

If you want to create a list from a collection you need to use the contstructor:

```
Return New List(Of Person)(
    From dr In dt.Rows Select New Person() With {
        .FirstName = dr.Item("FirstName").ToString(),
        .Surname = dr.Item("Surname").ToString()
    }
)
```

But the better option would be to just call `ToList` on your LINQ query:

```
Return (From dr In dt.Rows Select New Person() With {
    .FirstName = dr.Item("FirstName").ToString(),
    .Surname = dr.Item("Surname").ToString()
}).ToList()
```

Also, if you find it preferable, there is the extension method format which is a bit less wordy:

```
Return dt.Rows.Select(Function(dr) New Person() With {
                          .FirstName = dr.Item("FirstName").ToString(),
                          .Surname = dr.Item("Surname").ToString()
                          }).ToList()
```